# get autogenerated id of list item on click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Am trying to get the id of li on click event but it does not work,

```
 function dialougeboxclick(){
            alert('i am call here');
            console.log($(this));
            alert("attributes are"+$(this).attr());//undefined
            alert("id is "+$(this).attr("id"));//undefined
            alert("event id"+event.target.id);//empty
            $('#').removeClass('box-li').addClass('box-li selected');
        }
```

//dynamically populated li

```
$("#roster").append(
                    //uniquely identify it id="' + hashjid + '">
                '<li  class="box-li" onclick=dialougeboxclick() id="' + hashjid + '">' +
                                '<div class="ChatListContainer">'+
                                    '<div class="chatNameLeft">'+
                                        '<div><img src="../res/Chat/images/larry.png"></div>'+
                                        '<div id="' + jid + '" class="status">online</div>' +
                                    '</div>'+

                                    '<div class="chatDetailsRight inline-right">'+
                                        '<h4 class="mg-0 NameOfParticipant">'+name+'</h4>'+
                                        '<p class="mg-0 DesignationOfParticipant">CEO</p>'+
                '<p class="MessageOneLiner"><span class="readStatus Dblue">//</span>Sure, let me email it to you</p>'+

                                    '</div>'+
                                    '<span class="TimeStamp TimeStampBroadCastList">14:25 am</span>'+
                                '</div>'+
                            '</li>'
                          );
```

what is the problem ?? below is the hirarchy

```
  <div class="cont-box scroll">
                        <ul id="roster">
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Read about [__`Event delegation`__](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) as well...

Comment: what is the problem, you can see my effort

Comment: There is no problem, but SO has a similar question which has answer available..

Comment: I have tried it does not work for me?

    function dialougeboxclick(that) {
            alert("parent id"+$(this).parent().parent().attr("id"));//undefined ???

Comment: You did not change `this` to `that` :P

Comment: alert("parent id"+$(that).parent().parent().attr("id")); //still undefined what am doing wrong

should I change this behavior <li  class="box-li" onclick=dialougeboxclick(that)???

Comment: Debug what is `$(that).parent().parent()` and check whether that element has `id` attribute..